# Is there a way to automatically quote all the input that goes through the models/objects in Zend?

Tags: php, security, zend-framework

.. or do I have to go through each of my models/objects and use ->quote on every data input?

Comment: You could turn magic quotes on... wait, what?

Comment: What do you mean, where, how?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php

Comment: That was of no help - This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.

Comment: That's not my point, the point was to make you realize that this might be not so great idea.. :P

Comment: @Esailija: magic quotes were removed in php 5.4

Comment: I'll take it there's no way to do this and that it's probably a bad idea.

Comment: @TimFountain to avoid unwanted queries, for security, I thought it was obvious

Comment: It's still not very clear why you think you need this. Zend_Db will automatically quote values as they are inserted into the database as long as you are using parameterised queries (which you should be - see example #1 here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.statement.html).

Comment: Yes, that's the way to do it, but what happens when you have a 100 lines uber complicated query? Using parameterised queries would make it hard to read. (can't even imagine)

Comment: I think a 100-line query will be hard to read regardless.

Answer (score 0):

As you've probably understood from the comments this isn't such a brilliant idea, but If you really want to i quess that you could do something with func_get_args (http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) and overwrite the original variable, but it wouldn't be a pretty hack.

You could also do some tricks with $_POST and $_GET but all in all, it would probably not be a good solution either way.